# combine SUBSTR, COUNT and COUNT in SQL query

Tags: sql, count, sum, substr

I have a query which consists of `SUBSTR`, `COUNT` and `SUM` but it doesn't work. No data is returned. This is my query:

```
$query="SELECT COUNT(TYPE_A), SUM(HRGPASANG), SUM(HRGABULAN), SUM(HRGATAHUN) 
from namatabel where NIKAM='651290' 
AND (SUBSTR(end_date,7,4)=2013) 
AND SUBSTR(CNTRC_EDATE,4,2)=12) 
AND (TYPE_A='ZBSA'OR TYPE_A='ZMOS' OR TYPE_A='ZCSA')";
```

Comment: for which _RDBMS_  ? mysql >

Answer (score 0):

(SUBSTR(end_date,7,4)=2013)

Has you missed the quotes?

(SUBSTR(end_date,7,4)='2013')

Answer (score 0):

Try putting quotes on the values of your dates:

```
 $query="SELECT COUNT(TYPE_A), SUM(HRGPASANG), SUM(HRGABULAN), SUM(HRGATAHUN)
 FROM namatabel where NIKAM='651290' 
 AND (SUBSTR(end_date,7,4)='2013')
 AND SUBSTR(CNTRC_EDATE,4,2)='12') 
 AND (TYPE_A='ZBSA' OR TYPE_A='ZMOS' 
 OR TYPE_A='ZCSA')";
```

In this case both `2013` and `12` should have quotes.

Use also `IN()` function instead of `OR` clause, like:

```
 $query="SELECT COUNT(TYPE_A), SUM(HRGPASANG), SUM(HRGABULAN), SUM(HRGATAHUN)
 FROM namatabel where NIKAM='651290' 
 AND SUBSTR(end_date,7,4)='2013'
 AND SUBSTR(CNTRC_EDATE,4,2)='12'
 AND TYPE_A IN('ZBSA','ZMOS','ZCSA')";
```

Comment: i have tried to add quotes, but it still not work. the data return when query like this : 
$query="SELECT COUNT(TYPE_A), SUM(HRGPASANG), SUM(HRGABULAN), SUM(HRGATAHUN)
FROM namatabel where NIKAM='651290'
AND TYPE_A IN('ZBSA','ZMOS','ZCSA')";

but when i add "AND SUBSTR(end_date,7,4)='2013'
 AND SUBSTR(CNTRC_EDATE,4,2)='12'" no data appears. 

and when i try to chek this :
$query="SELECT COUNT(TYPE_A), SUM(HRGPASANG), SUM(HRGABULAN), SUM(HRGATAHUN)
 FROM namatabel
 where SUBSTR(end_date,7,4)='2013'
 AND SUBSTR(CNTRC_EDATE,4,2)='12'
 AND TYPE_A IN('ZBSA','ZMOS','ZCSA')"; the data is return

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DATEPART function to get correct numbers of SQL instead of substring.

See below

```
SELECT COUNT(TYPE_A), SUM(HRGPASANG), SUM(HRGABULAN), SUM(HRGATAHUN) 
FROM namatabel 
WHERE NIKAM='651290' 
AND DATEPART(YYYY,end_date)=2013 
AND DATEPART(MM,CNTRC_EDATE)=12 
AND TYPE_A IN ('ZBSA','ZMOS','ZCSA')
```